# Select IDs of lines where nvarchar column cannot convert into date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's make it super simple: 2 columns, `id` and `textDate`.

For some of the lines, the `textDate` field will contains null, which is ok, sometimes it will contains something like '2017-06-24' which is also ok.

But for some of the lines (and this should've been validated before it got to this point) the field will contains 'A value placed there to complicate things'.

I want to know which line aren't null and does not follow the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

I searched but it's so specific that my search didn't lead anywhere to what I needed.

Comment: check out `TRY_CAST`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: ...and storing dates using, I don't know, the date data type. That's what it's for, and prevents you from having to validate anything. :-)

Comment: Select * from YourTable where try_convert(date,textDate) is null and textDate is not null

Comment: If you want to ensure that the date is in one particular format, `yyyy-mm-dd` as opposed to either `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`, then you should include a date and time style code in your call to try_convert, e.g.: `try_convert(date, textDate, 23) is null -- find invalid values` Ref: [Date and time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would not make this mistake myself, previous php devs made a ton of mistakes and I need to correct them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ISDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql) for this:

```
-- Create a table for the dummy data
create table #data
(
    id int,
    textDate varchar(100)
)

-- Add some dummy values to the table
insert into #data values
(1, NULL),
(2, '2017-06-24'),
(3, 'A value placed there to complicate things')

-- Return records which aren't valid dates (or NULL)
select 
    *
from #data
where isdate(textDate) = 0 and textDate is not null

drop table #data
```

As mentioned in the comments, you could also consider [`TRY_CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) or [`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) if you prefer.